# Квадратные ячейки JTable

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте!
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать ячейки JTable квадратными. И что бы при изменении размеров окна, ячейки изменяли размер, но оставались квадратными ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу причин почему бы это не сделать...

Есть метод `JTable.setRowHeight()` - почему бы не привязать вызов этого метода к размеру окна?